# What's the best way to add a CSS file to the XHTML page

Tags: css, xhtml

Option 1 `<?xml-stylesheet?>`

```
<?xml-stylesheet href="style.css" type="text/css"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<title>Title</title>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Option 2 `<link/>`

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<title>Title</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Both works. Just wondering which is better.
Thanks.

Comment: if you are using xhtml, don't forget to close your link tag: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />`

Comment: @Pete: Good point - I hadn't seen the markup that was added to the question. The page wouldn't even display if this was being served as XML, precisely because of that error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<link>` is more cross-browser compatible. Having *anything* before the DOCTYPE declaration tends to lead to unexpected results, especially in older browsers.

Furthermore, `<?xml-stylesheet?>` is designed for XML. Unless you're sure your XHTML page is being served in XML mode you should avoid it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Second option is more comfortable to use still if you have to link more than one stylesheet then you would like to add `<link>` easily.

Comment: But it's just as easy to add more `<?xml-stylesheet?>` statements for linking to more than one stylesheet.

Comment: @BoltClock stylesheets in href with a space? n + 1 for your ans.